# Сетеры и гетеры для Jackson де\сериализации

Tags: java, json, jackson

Для десериализации и сериализации использую библиотеку Jackson. Иногда на практике встречаюсь с требованием прописать сеттеры для класса сущности, т.к. десериализация не хочет работать. 
От модификатора доступа это не зависит. Зачем Jackson иногда это требует если он использует рефлексию?

```
class Example {
 private String field;
}
```

...

```
String json = "{\"field\": \"test\"}";   
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Example example = mapper.readValue(json, Example.class);
```

Comment: Если бы вы использовали анотации, то тогда не нужно было бы

Answer (score 2):

Да по умолчанию Jackson использует геттеры и сеттеры для сериализации и десериализации, однако как он только не конфигурируется.

Если Вы инициализируете `ObjectMapper` вот так, то он будет использовать поля:

```
ObjectMapper mapper  = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
                .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
```

Comment: Запутало то что для десириализации достаточно будет и гетера, тогда как логически предположить что нужно использовать сетер.  Jackson видать использует гетер для идентификации поля а потом для его заполения использует все-таки рекурсию?

Comment: @JavaJunior Наверно Вы имеете в виду рефлексию, чесслово не проверял как он действительно делает и не могу сейчас - с телефона отвечаю, однако можете Вы, добавьте логгирование во все методы и увидите... или бряки поставьте

Comment: Да рефлексию. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: @JavaJunior рад помочь, обращайтесь

Comment: Нашел: "Unintuitively, the getter also makes the private field deserializable as well – because once it has a getter, the field is considered a property." - дает понят зачем все-таки гетер для десириализации